# Functions attached to string prototypes within scope only

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6, prototype-programming

It is very simple to add methods to classes such as `String` prototypically. However, this affects all strings in the global scope.

How can I add a method accessible from all string literals like such: `"foo".bar()`, such that that method is only accessible within the scope of an ES6 class, say, or a function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am afraid that you may not be able to do that. Also it seems like it's a bad idea.
It will be probably better if you just use normal function. Like: `bar("foo")`

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. Strings are primitives. They are coerced to `String` instances when being used like objects (and thus can use `String.prototype` methods). This behaviour doesn't depend on the scope.

For

```
class Superstring extends String {
  bar() {
    return `${this} bar`;
  }
}
```

it can be

```
new Superstring('foo').bar();
```

or

```
const bar = (str) => Superstring.prototype.bar.call(str);

bar('foo');
```